# 'LoginButton Control' sample for Facebook SDK for .NET do not show GraphUser objects

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to learn using the Facebook SDK for .NET. Specifically for Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App (not Silverlight). For this I have build the 'LoginButton Control' sample that can be found here: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/controls/login-ui-control/
I have sucessfully logged in to Facebook with the sample, but the 'Name' newer shows up. It is related to this part of the code:

```
        <!--user information-->
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding CurrentUser.Name, ElementName=loginButton}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

It seems that 'CurrentUser.x' is not able to retrieve other data like ID, Name etc. For further testing, I added the 'ProfilePicture Control' sample. It turns out that the profile picture shows fine, but all other GraphUser objects cannot be shown.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, Facebook 6.8.0, Facebook.Client 1.0.2.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this sample do not give access to GraphUser objects?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone!! I had the same problem you had but however I managed to get it done after spending 6 hours. The documentation of Nuget Facebook SDK seems outdated and not properly written. This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310848/facebooksdk-net-publish-not-working-cant-get-loginbutton-currentsession-to-pu) helped me a lot.

Here is the Xaml I used.`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Ganesh" Grid.Row="0" 
    FontSize="72" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Text="Welcome" 
    Foreground="Red"
    Visibility="Collapsed"/>

<facebookControls:LoginButton 
    x:Name="loginButton" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    SessionStateChanged="loginButton_SessionStateChanged"/>

<facebookControls:ProfilePicture 
    x:Name="profilePicture"
    Width="50" 
    Height="50" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    CropMode="Original" 
    Grid.Row="3"/>

<TextBlock x:Name="userInfo"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Text=""
    FontSize="20"
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Foreground="#FF8B2020"
    Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

`

And here is the Xaml.Cs
[image]

Include all necessary namespaces. 
This code was not neatly written. It was for test. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please give more info on outdated parts? In my case the SessionStateChanged is called with Openin and Closed but never Opened after redirecting to the Login page with a LoginButton. After following the "configuration" and "login button" tutorials.