# Fetch User Data in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

This is not intented to be a double post, even that it is bacially the same challenge I have.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, Facebook 6.8.0, Facebook.Client 1.0.2. Programming for Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App (not Silverlight).

It is really frustrating. I can not get the samples that they have provided at their website to work properly.  I have made the example shown here:
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/howtos/fetch-user-data/

First I tried "Step 3 - A: Fetch User Data using the Facebook SDK".

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RetriveUserInfo() {var client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(this.loginButton.CurrentSession.AccessToken);

dynamic result = await client.GetTaskAsync("me");
var currentUser = new Facebook.Client.GraphUser(result);

this.userInfo.Text = this.BuildUserInfoDisplay(currentUser);}
```

Here "this.loginButton.CurrentSession.AccessToken" comes with an error, as there are no definition for CurrentSession.AccessToken.

Then I tried "Step 3 - B: Fetch User Data using the Login Control".
The app will log me in, but non of the user info is shown anywhere. I found that 'OnUserInfoChanged' from facebookControls:LoginButton are newer triggered.

What is going on - are the samples outdated? How do I fetch the User data?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367101/loginbutton-control-sample-for-facebook-sdk-for-net-do-not-show-graphuser-obj/30008549#30008549)..
References: 
1. [facebooksdk.net publish not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310848/facebooksdk-net-publish-not-working-cant-get-loginbutton-currentsession-to-pu) 
2. [Fetch User Data](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/howtos/fetch-user-data/)
3. [Login Button Control](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/controls/login-ui-control/)

Comment: It would be better to flag the double posted question than amplify the problem by double posting your answer. :)